# two-dimensional spiral curve in python

Tags: python, spiral

How to plot a two-dimensional spiral curve.

I have the following equation:

```
x = r(theta) x cos(theta)

y = r(theta) x sin(theta)

r = a x theta
```

a is an arbitrary constant.

How could I use these equation to plot this figure?

Comment: Learn how to use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). There are various tutorials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.